# Strange result of an infinite sum

Tags: summation

I have the following definition:

```
o[a_] := Sum[  x^(2 k + 1) Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - a^2, {i, 0, 
  k - 1}]/((2 k + 1)!), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

Now when I evaluate

```
o[1]
(* 0 *)
```

Which I don't believe is correct. Also, changing the definition to

```
o[a_] := Sum[  x^(2 k + 1) Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - a^2, {i, 0, 
  k - 1}]/((2 k + 1)!), {k, 0, 1000}]
```

Or some other large number it does yield the correct result: $x$.

So am I overlooking something here and does this make sense, or is this a bug?

---

To be clear, here is my reasoning for why is should be $x$:

$$o(1)=\frac{x}{1!}\prod_{i=0}^{-1}((2i+1)^2-1)+\frac{x^3}{3!}\prod_{i=0}^{0}((2i+1)^2-1)+\frac{x^5}{5!}\prod_{i=0}^{1}((2i+1)^2-1)+....$$
And here the product in the first term is empty, so evaluates to $1$, and all other products have a factor $1^2-1=0$, so they all evaluate to $0$. So in total the result will just be $x$.

---

So is it fair to say this is a bug?

Comment: I think `o[1]=0` is correct (nice choice of function name btw ;). You have a product that starts at `i=0` and when `i=0` and `a=1` you get `Product[1^2-1]` for the first element, which is zero. Hence the whole product becomes zero, since zero times anything is zero. Then the sum of zeros is zero.

Comment: @Nasser No,  in the first term of the sum the product runs from $i=0$ to $i=k-1=-1$, which is empty, and thus should be one. Multiplied by $x^{2k+1}=x$, this should return $x$. All other terms do have this $0$ term in the product you describe and thus will all be $0$. So in total the single $x$ should be the result

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but can this theory of yours also explain the difference between summing to $\infty$ and summing to say $1000$?

Comment: I tried it on Maple, and it also gave zero. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0N9mv.png)  so this means it is highly unlikely the result by Mathematica is wrong.

Comment: @Nasser Can you take a look at my edit and tell me if something is not correct? Again, maybe I'm just overlooking something here.

Comment: As for the second case, Mathematica result is not the same as Maple. Maple also gave zero. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nupo6.png)  so there is possibility Mathematica result is wrong for the second case.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the generic symbolic  `Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - 1^2, {i, 0, k - 1}]` vs. specific numeric ones, `Table[Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - 1^2, {i, 0, k - 1}], {k, 0, 3}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes I think it does a bit premature optimization by just assuming the $k-1$ will be $\geq 0$, while that of course need not be the case

Comment: Please do not add the `bugs` tag to new questions you posted.  It is meant to be added later, after it is confirmed by the community.  This is mentioned in the description of the tag.

Comment: I would not consider the fact that `Product[x, {x, 0, a}]` evaluates to `0` a bug.

Comment: Consider `Product[x, {x, 0, a}, GenerateConditions -> True]` to see how `Product` treats a symbolic product (from the docs: "The upper product limit is assumed to be an integer distance from the lower limit").

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate the term first, the result is

```
Sin[a ArcSin[x]]/a
```

which, when assigned to `o[a_]`, will further evaluate to `x` for `o[1]`.

So, the solution to your problem would be to

1. Evaluate the term
2. Then define `o[a_]` on the result.

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite getting what you mean. I see that it evaluates to the expression, but I don't understand how that causes these problems? Shouldn't filling in $a=1$ in my definition that still evaluate to  $\frac{\sin (1\arcsin x)}{1}=x$?

Comment: @user2520938: I would think so, too, but alas, it doesn't. As soon as `SetDelayed` is involved, the output seems messed up. I tried `o[a_,kmax_,x_]=...` (resulting in a longer expression) and then tried `o[1,kmax,x]`, but this yields indeterminate expression errors. At the moment, my answer seems the only way to go.

Comment: Oke thanks for your time and answer. I'll just use this solution for now. I won't accept the answer just yet, because I'm curious for more input on this.

Comment: @user2520938: Good idea, because there are people around here, who are much more knowledgeable on *Mathematica* than I am. Maybe you also found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Amplifying on @Jinxed answer:

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
o[a_] := Sum[
  x^(2 k + 1) Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - a^2, {i, 0, 
      k - 1}]/((2 k + 1)!), {k, 0, Infinity}]

o[a]
```

> Sin[a*ArcSin[x]]/a

```
o[0]
```

> ArcSin[x]

```
Limit[o[a], a -> 0]
```

> ArcSin[x]

```
o[0] // Trace
```

[image]

```
term[k_] = 
 x^(2 k + 1) Product[(2 i + 1)^2 - a^2, {i, 0, k - 1}]/((2 k + 1)!) //
   FullSimplify
```

> (4^k*x^(1 + 2*k)*Cos[(a*Pi)/2]*Gamma[1/2 - a/2 + k]*
>         Gamma[(1 + a)/2 + k])/(Pi*Gamma[2 + 2*k])

```
o2[a_] = Sum[term[k], {k, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
```

> Sin[a*ArcSin[x]]/a

```
Limit[o2[a], a -> 0]
```

> ArcSin[x]